# Issue with formatting an output file

Tags: java, io, formatting, printf

So I am currently having an issue with formatting with an output file that I create using an input file.  The input file(file.txt) has this information with in it, *exactly as seen here:*

```
32 54 67.5 29 35 80 

115 44.5 100 65
```

I want to print the output file where the numbers are in a vertical line with a total of all the numbers added up at the bottom of the line.
The code for doing this (that I'm trying to use) is -

```
         while(in.hasNextDouble()) 
         {
         double value = in.nextDouble();
         out.printf("%15.2f\n", value);
         total += value;
         }
         out.printf("Total: %8.2f\n", total);
```

It seems to print all the numbers on the same line instead of one after another.  Am I missing a piece in the formatting?  I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Is the language Java or C?

Comment: Maybe try `\n\r`...

Answer (score 1):

Use `%n` instead of `/n` i.e.

```
out.printf("%15.2f%n", value);
```

`%n` is platform independent newline character. Refer [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

`/n` may work sometimes, but not always with `printf`.